# differentiate the above

Tags: calculus

I do not understand how to differentiate the two functions below based on examples in my book. Could you please differentiate the following (with some minor explanation) thank you

a) $f(x)=5e^x \sin{x}$

b) $f(x)=\frac{5\sin{x}}{e^{-x}}$

Comment: Do you understand the product rule and the quotient rule for differentiation?

Comment: yes but how do you apply it to these two. I get confused about these more complicated functions

Comment: @CashVai There is only one rule for learning these kinds of techniques: whenever you cannot do a problem, change it so that it is just a little bit simpler.  If you still cannot solve it, do so again.  When you finally reach something you can solve, then you will know, very very specifically, what is causing you trouble.  Often, the trouble disappears as soon as you see it, but at least you are able to ask the perfect question, and appreciate the answer fully.  This saves a huge amount of time in the long run, because it means that you need to learn each lesson only one, not ten times...

Answer (score 1):

Using the the product rule: $(f(x)\times g(x))'=f'(x)\times g(x)+g'(x)\times f(x)$,
we can see that we have to find $f'(x)$ and $g'(x)$.

Now our function, $f(x)\times g(x)=5e^x \sin(x)$. So we can say that $f(x)=5e^x$ and $g(x)=\sin(x)$. Now you have to find the derivative of each and use the product rule.

The derivative of $\sin(x)$ is $\cos(x)$. Similarly, the derivative of $5e^x$ is $5e^x$ since 5 is a constant and since the derivative of $e^{ax}$ is $ae^{ax}$ (in this case a=1).

$\therefore (f(x)×g(x))′= f′(x)×g(x)+g′(x)×f(x)= 5e^x \sin(x) + \cos(x) 5e^x $

b) Same idea for part b, you can use the product rule or quotient rule; it just matters how you look at the function as suggested by @Oliver Bel

$\frac{5\sin(x)}{e^{-x}}=5e^x\sin(x) \implies $ same as a

Answer (score 1):

$[1]$ $(\sin x )' = \cos x $

$[2]$ $(e^x)' = e^x $

$[3]$ $(fg)' = f'g+fg' $

$$[4] \; \; \; \; \; ( \frac{f}{g})' = \frac{ f'g - fg'}{g^2} $$

Apply $1,2,3,4$ to your functions, and you will get desired results!